# What mean the "(2)" for the umask?

Tags: windows, git, git-init

Git for Windows.
I am reading [this](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) documentation about the `git init` command:

> **--shared[=(false|true|umask|group|all|world|everybody|0xxx)]** 
> Specify that the Git repository is to be shared amongst several users. This
>   allows users belonging to the same group to push into that repository.
>   When specified, the config variable "`core.sharedRepository`" is set so
>   that files and directories under `$GIT_DIR` are created with the
>   requested permissions. When not specified, Git will use permissions
>   reported by `umask(2)`.

What mean the "`(2)`" for the `umask`? I see such variant of value (`umask`) exists for the `--shared` option. Is it the same?

The `git help umask` finds nothing.

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply refers to the section 2 of manual pages:

```
man 2 umask
```

> Pages are traditionally referred to using the notation "name(section)": for example, ftp(1). The same page name may appear in more than one section of the manual, such as when the names of system calls, user commands, or macro packages coincide. Examples are man(1) and man(7), or exit(2) and exit(3).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page

Comment: I use Windows OS. I got this result: `bash: man: command not found`

Comment: This is a Linux/Unix specific thing. I'm not sure umask apply to Windows.

Comment: This was my first guess too. Sadly: `No manual entry for umask in section 2`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider it depends on you distro, CentOS minimal doesn't include it by default, while Ubuntu does for example.

Comment: How can I get (in the Windows OS) the help for the umask(2)?

Comment: @Bush like I said in my previous command, umask is a POSIX filesystem attribute that is highly OS dependant. I'm pretty sure there's no native support for umask on Windows (cygwin and friends might emulate it though). You should just skip this. If you're currious about umask on POSIX systems, you can read the Linux man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html